# How can I use a different form of regex for each line in a file?

Tags: python, regex, line

```
with open('ch4_int_coord.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line1 = re.search(r'\w{1,2}', f)
        line2 = re.search(r'\w{1,2}\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\.+\d+', int_coord)
        print line1
```

this is what I have so far. I'm trying to use a new regex pattern for each line in the file (since each has a different amount of data)but I'm not sure how to specify this.

Comment: one brute force way - put each of the patterns in a list and then use them in your loop

Comment: How do you get `line1`, `line2` and so on? better put the patterns in a list and iterate just like the lines of your file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to preserve your regexes and access them with a simple indexing, can put the relative number of lines as the key and iterate over the file object using `enumerate` function in order to access to the line index.

```
regex_dict={1:r'\w{1,2}',2:r'\w{1,2}\s+(\d+)\s+\d+\.+\d+'}
with open('ch4_int_coord.txt') as f:
    for index,line in enumerate(f,1):
        print re.search(regex_dict[index],line)
```